# ListBox generates -1 on initial select (if below displayed text)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

When I populate my ListBox with the contents of a simple short text file, everything works as expected, however, if I *initially* click in the listbox below the filled text area (ie below the 9 lines read in), listbox returns an index of `-1`. I.e., my listbox is sized to display more than 9 lines.

This only happens the first time. If I select one of the text lines, then `-1` never shows up again, even if I click below the text area.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ListBoxProblem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.txt");

            string line = "";
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);

            sr.Close();
            btn_Read.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int idx = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            // MessageBox.Show("{0} -- {1}", idx.ToString(), (listBox1.Items[idx]).ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(idx.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[idx].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

the simple text data file I'm using:

```
Alpine Visa,3412.5,21.25
American Express,105,11.65
Chase Visa,5795,13.5
Citibank Visa,-2.3,18
Discover Card,153.25,12.65
Kmart,32.21,13.66
Marshall Fields,265.32,14
River Forest Mastercard,250.65,17
Sears,-45.3,14.3
```

I can check for `-1` in my code and deal with this, but I'd like to understand ***why*** this is happening in the first place. This is part of a larger program, but I extracted the relevant code (hence the hardcoded filename/missing check) to just show the problem.

For that matter, can anyone also tell me why the commented out `MessageBox.Show()` call didn't work? It seems equivalent to the other two. I'm new to C# and WinForms.

**EDIT**: a nice simple alternative/solution to the `MessageBox.Show()` question I had:

`MessageBox.Show($"{idx}  {(listBox1.Items[idx])}");`

Comment: It is documented as such: [ListBox.SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) -   _"A zero-based index of the currently selected item. A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected."_

Comment: Some might consider it a bug, some not.  Always check for -1 before accessing the array.  What didn't work with the MessageBox.Show?  Missing `String.Format(...` ?

Comment: @stuartd What I don't understand is that this only happens with the first/initial selection. Once I select one of the other lines, I can't get this behavior, so I don't think it's consistent with the quote you provide. I first thought this might be a timing related issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: To make sure I understand the problem: You populate a `ListBox` with a few items. You click the blank whitespace where there is no item. Your `SelectedIndex` is `-1` (as @stuartd said, that makes sense). Then you click an actual item and get `1` for the `SelectedIndex`. Then if you click back onto the blank space, you do not get `-1` for the index?

Comment: _"Once I select one of the other lines, I can't get this behavior,"_ that's because an item is now selected..

Comment: @sab669 Yes, that's right .. if I select the 3rd item (Chase) initially, I get an index of 2, and then everything else works fine and no invalid index is generated regardless where I click. However, if I start by clicking below the area where the text is displayed, I get an index of -1 ..

Comment: @LarsTech with re the MessageBox, I get this error message: `cannot convert from string to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'` .. (not a true copy-paste, not able to do this). MessageBox seems to think this is an additional parameter to it. I just tried surrounding both arguments with a set of parenthesis, but that's not working either .. odd.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but I can duplicate the behavior and I suspect this is "working as intended". If you change your `SelectionMode` to `MultiSimple`, you can select an item and then de-select it and you'll notice your `SelectedIndex` is now `-1`. So it's probably just some weird quirk of the way Single Select works. "Nothing's selected but they clicked on the ListBox, do *something*!" then you click again "OK we've got something selected and they didn't select anything, so ignore that"

Comment: And in response to your response to Lars, you should do `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} -- {1}", firstVal, secondVal));`. You're calling some overload of `MessageBox.Show` that expects a `MessageBoxButtons` parameter,  not the "default" `MessageBox.Show(string)` that you think you're calling

Comment: @sab669 Thanks for confirming this - being new to WinForms/.net/C# - but not coding -  I can't always tell if it's me or it :) For now I just check for an index of `-`1 before I proceed, but it did catch me off guard when I encountered this last night. And yes, the more explicit use of `string.Format()` works - thanks.

Comment: Understandable. FYI [Microsoft makes all of their source code available online](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/). It will surely come in handy in the future. I was digging through the ListBox code to see if I could figure out exactly how they handle the selection behavior but I couldn't make sense of it. Didn't look very thoroughly though.

Comment: @sab669 Oh, I didn't realize that - thanks!. I've been looking for a good resource/overview for coding with WinForms (something that goes over the various controls etc) - but there doesn't seem anything relatively recent that does that. Most recent stuff seems to focus on WPF - which I'll eventually get to at some point. It's a lot of fun regardless.